# How to htaccess-redirect single directory to external URL, while URL-masking

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, forwarding, url-masking

There are many similar questions here, but none seem to be exactly the same, and something is tripping me up.
I have one specific internal URL, **mydomain.com/a-directory**, that I want to forward to the external URL **https://mailchi.mp/mydomain.com/a-directory** , while still keeping the browser's shown URL as **mydomain.com/a-directory**.

I have tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com/a-directory$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://mailchi.mp/mydomain.com/a-directory [P]  

</IfModule>
```

And also:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^a-directory$ https://mailchi.mp/mydomain.com/a-directory [P]

</IfModule>
```

Apache mod_proxy is installed.
Edit: Both seem to be mostly ignored, as no forwarding is happening, and it's not crashing. The browser is just saying that the page can't be found, as [www.httpmydomain.dom/a-directory](http://www.httpmydomain.dom/a-directory) doesn't exist.

Edit:
The .htaccess file contains the following.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted access"
AuthUserFile /home/cpanelUser/.htpasswd
Require valid-user


#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\.(?!well-known).*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|composer\.(json|lock))$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig\.save)$">
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# Override PHP settings that cannot be changed at runtime. See
# sites/default/default.settings.php and drupal_environment_initialize() in
# includes/bootstrap.inc for settings that can be changed at runtime.

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
  php_flag register_globals                 off
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com/a-directory$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) https://mailchi.mp/mydomain.com/a-directory [P] 

  # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
  # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
  # you don't bounce between http and https.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

  # Make sure Authorization HTTP header is available to PHP
  # even when running as CGI or FastCGI.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
  # includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
  # Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as well
  # as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch directive
  # above.
  #
  # NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without mod_rewrite, it is
  # not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess, because
  # <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
  #
  # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
  # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
  # downloaded.
  RewriteRule "/\.|^\.(?!well-known/)" - [F]

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # 2 Redirect to HTTPS
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^blog2
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/phpinfo.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico

  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  
  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Add headers to all responses.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Disable content sniffing, since it's an attack vector.
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^anotherAliasDomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.anotherAliasDomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the â€œea-php72â€ package as the default â€œPHPâ€ programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "All without luck" - what happens exactly? (Isn't `/a-directory` the "external URL"?)

Comment: Ýour RewriteCond makes no sense. `mydomain.com/a-directory` is not a host name.

Comment: Apologies for my lacking post. I have made some edits to add more useful/complete information.

Comment: Is `/a-directory` also a physical directory on the file system? Is mod_rewrite installed? (You should remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper.) Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: /a-directory is not a directory on the file system. mod_rewrite is installed.

Comment: Is `.htaccess` itself enabled? Your 2nd example should do "something" for a request to `/a-directory` - even if it's an error?

Comment: And yes, the `.htaccess` file is otherwise a Drupal 7 standard .htaccess file. Apparently I can't post it here, so I will have to edit my original post to add it..

Comment: Yes, .htaccess is enabled.  I know this because the first section is a password protection that currently works just fine.

Comment: "a Drupal 7 standard .htaccess file." - although the code you posted appears to be missing all the standard front-controller (mod_rewrite) directives? Are these present in the file?

Comment: @MrWhite , I have updated my original post with the entire contents of the .htaccess file. I didn't think it matters what comes after the [P] flag as it should stop processing at that point, but I may be mistaken there.

Comment: "I didn't think it matters what comes after the [P] flag" - Yes, but it wasn't clear in your previous post where exactly you were placing your proxy redirect directives (it sounded like you were perhaps placing them at the very end of your `.htaccess` file - after other mod_rewrite directives). The location looks OK, however, you are using the wrong directives (as noted in comments above) - these will indeed not do anything. (You do have a spurious redirect at the end - I guess added by cPanel - which probably isn't doing anything.)

Comment: @CBroe , I have modified it to:
`RewriteCond ^https://www\.mydomain\.com/a-directory$`
But that gives a 500 Internal Server Error instead. Would you be able to offer an example of what you believe would work instead?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com/a-directory$
> RewriteRule ^(.*) https://mailchi.mp/example.com/a-directory [P]
> ```

> I have modified it to: `RewriteCond ^https://www\.example\.com/a-directory$`

Whilst the code is in the correct place (although it is before the HTTP to HTTPS redirect, so you might be trying to proxy an HTTP request), you are not using the correct directives (although the 2nd code block in your question *is* correct, providing the two domains  point to different servers).

Neither of the above two *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives) make much sense. The 2nd condition above is syntactically invalid as you are missing the first (or second?) argument.

The `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains the value of the `Host` HTTP request header. eg. If you request `http://example.com/a-directory` then `HTTP_HOST` contains `example.com`. However, if you request `http://www.example.com/a-directory` then `HTTP_HOST` will contain `www.example.com`.

So, if you are requesting `http://example.com/a-directory` then the directive you should be using is as per your second code block:

```
RewriteRule ^a-directory$ https://mailchi.mp/example.com/a-directory [P]
```

If you specifically need to check the requested host then:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^a-directory$ https://mailchi.mp/example.com/a-directory [P]
```

However, assuming the target server allows you to *proxy* requests via this URL (they could block you) then you may still need additional directives in your server config / virtualhost to correctly configure the reverse proxy. Notably the `ProxyPassReverse` directive. Without this, if the target server issued an HTTP redirect then the user would be redirected away from your domain (`example.com`).